# When should a complex type be declared by directly naming the element, as opposed to using the type attribute?

Tags: xsd

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex.asp

**In this following snippit, why should the first way ever be used over the second?**

> We can define a complex element in an XML Schema two different ways:
>
> A. The "employee" element can be declared directly by naming the element, like this:

```
<xs:element name="employee">   
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>   
 </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

> If you use the method described above, only the "employee" element can
>   use the specified complex type. Note that the child elements,
>   "firstname" and "lastname", are surrounded by the 
>   indicator. This means that the child elements must appear in the same
>   order as they are declared. You will learn more about indicators in
>   the XSD Indicators chapter.
>
> B. The "employee" element can have a type attribute that refers to the name of the complex type to use:

```
<xs:complexType name="personinfo">   
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>  
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

> If you use the method described above, several elements can refer to
>   the same complex type, like this:

```
<xs:element name="employee" type="personinfo"/> 
<xs:element name="student" type="personinfo"/>
<xs:element name="member" type="personinfo"/>

<xs:complexType name="personinfo">  
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>   
 </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

**Why should the first way ever be used over the second?**

Answer (score 1):

Local types can be useful for elements which should not be reused outside of some specific context.  It would make sense, for example, for elements representing table cells to be local to the types used for table rows, and for the declaration of table-row elements to be local to the type used for the element representing the table as a whole.  (An element representing a table row does not -- on this account -- make any sense outside the context of a table.  Making declarations local is a simple way of ensuring that elements which place particular demands on their contexts can only be used in those contexts.)

Local types in XSD can also (like local types in other languages) also be useful in avoiding name collisions.  If my vocabulary provides for letters to have a salutation tagged `salutation`, and also provides for database-like information about people in which their names, addresses, and the preferred form of address (tagged `salutation`) are recorded, the two elements named `salutation` are likely to be regarded as wholly unrelated to each other; making one or both of them local allows them both to exist within a vocabulary.  (Namespaces can also be used for this purpose, but I have met few vocabulary designers who would want to put these two salutation elements into different namespaces, and even fewer XML users who would greet that prospect with anything but distaste.)

If you're not interested in preventing re-use, stressing the semantic dependency of an element on its parent, or avoiding name collisions, then there isn't much reason to use local elements.  (That said, many people do use them quite a lot, and perhaps they have reasons I don't understand.  From where I sit, it just seems that many people overuse local declarations for no good reason at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Some GUI XSD editors only support the directly declaring complex types although you can quite often manually create the types if you do want to be able to reuse complex types.
So in that situation I would only go for declaring re-usable complex types if there is reuse of types just because it is easier not to declare reusable complex types.